# select data for every 5 minute interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query which is giving me 24 hour interval data, I want to get the data for every 5 minute interval

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytemptable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #mytemptable; 
SELECT  AVG( CAST ([PT_100SCALED_VAL0] AS bigint)  ) AS PT_100SCALED_VAL0_AVERAGE 
INTO #MYTEMPTABLE  FROM ( SELECT t1.[timestamp], t1.[PT_100SCALED_VAL0] FROM 
[REPORT] t1 WHERE t1.[timestamp] >= '2016-01-06 00:00:00' and  t1.[timestamp] <='2016-01-06 23:59:59'   ) 
TEMPTABLE 
SELECT t1.[timestamp], t1.[PT_100SCALED_VAL0]  , RM_temp.* FROM [REPORT]
t1 , #MYTEMPTABLE RM_temp  WHERE  t1.[timestamp] >= '2016-01-06 00:00:00' and  t1.[timestamp] <='2016-01-06 23:59:59' -- This select will give the final result.
```

my result for the above query is

```
timestamp   PT_100SCALED_VAL0   PT_100SCALED_VAL0_AVERAGE
2016-01-06 13:31:27.807 1   5
2016-01-06 13:32:27.810 2   5
2016-01-06 13:33:27.817 3   5
2016-01-06 13:34:27.827 4   5
2016-01-06 13:35:27.827 5   5
2016-01-06 13:36:27.837 6   5
2016-01-06 13:37:27.840 7   5
2016-01-06 13:38:27.847 8   5
2016-01-06 13:39:27.850 9   5
```

my expected result is

```
timestamp                 PT_100SCALED_VAL0 PT_100SCALED_VAL0_AVERAGE
2016-01-06 13:35:27.827   5                 5    
2016-01-06 13:39:27.850   9                 5
```

I have tried using with and partion by but i am getting error incorrect syntax near if

Comment: Just change the where clause...

Comment: can't change the where clause because its for a particular date and time and with in that date and time need to generate for every 5 minute interval. WITH #CTE AS (SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2016-01-06', [timestamp])/300 
ORDER BY [timestamp] DESC) from #gen) something like this to be done

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @start datetime, @end datetime
Select @start=CAST(CAST(getdate() as date) as datetime), @end=CAST((DATEADD(DAY,1,@start)) as datetime)
;With DateTimeSequence( Dt ) as
(
    Select @start as Stime
        union all
    Select DATEADD(MINUTE,5,Dt)
        from DateTimeSequence
        where Dt < DATEADD(MINUTE,-5,@end) 
)select Dt as StartTime,DATEADD(MINUTE,5,Dt)  as EndTime from DateTimeSequence
Option (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

Use the above CTE with your query and join with your query and use as desired.